# erasing an element from a string vector

Tags: c++, string, vector

In my program I have created a `vector` of `string` type (`vector<string> names;`).
After putting some values in it, I came in the situation where I wish to erase an element from it. I know that I can do this by typing: `names.erase(<pointer to the element to be erased>);`

However the only thing i know is that I wish to erase the element `i` (`i` is a counter in a loop). The starting position (pointer) of the `i`'th position is uknown, because the vector is a string (i.e. If it was an int vector I could do:

```
names.erase(names.begin()+i*sizeof(int))
```

Would someone please explain how I can find the position in memory of the `i`'th element, or generally how I can erase the `i`'th element without knowing its position.

Comment: Just `names.erase(names.begin()+i);`, as long as `i` is a valid index.

Comment: @user3374378 - What made you conclude that this was valid? `names.erase(names.begin()+i*sizeof(int))`.  In that example, you are erasing the value located at position i*sizeof(int) in the vector, and not the i'th entry in the vector.

Comment: I came up with this because the erase() function takes as a parameter a pointer to the starting position of the element to be deleted. However as Joseph explained, this is achieved by names.begin()+i.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter about the size of the elements. `names.begin() + i` gives you an iterator to the `i`th element of the vector. You don't move an iterator along in byte steps - you move it along an element at a time.

You definitely should not be doing `names.begin() + i * sizeof(int)` if you have a vector of `int`s. And even if it were the case that you had to add the size in bytes like this, the size of a `std::string` object is always fixed, regardless of the length of the string. That is `sizeof(std::string)` is a constant value. In fact, the size of any type is fixed in C++.

Comment: Thanks, you have been very helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

You definitely should use iterators to manipulate vector.
The simplest way to locate `i`'th element is:

```
std::vector<string>::iterator l_it(names.begin());
l_it += i;
```

Also be careful with erasing, because `std::vector::erase` relocates the rest of array (and moves indexes).

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/

Answer (score 0):

need to use iterator as below

```
        vector<string>::iterator lIter = lStrVec.begin();
        lIter = (lIter + (i-1));
        lStrVec.erase(lIter);
```

Note that if yu need to erase i th element move forward the iterator by i-1